# How to access data written in a socket without reading it

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, c

I'm working on an embedded system having Linux.
A client thread is writing some data in the socket but what server thread is reading on the other side isn't the same as it was written. Which is causing the thread (and parent process)  to crash.

I'm new to networking and Linux.
I have dumped every piece of data which is being written, it's all fine.

The function trace in gdb shows the following information.

```
(gdb) 
#0  0x00007f62be8e8670 in getenv () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f62be92057a in __libc_message () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007f62be99f927 in __fortify_fail () from /lib/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007f62be99f8f0 in __stack_chk_fail () from /lib/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000406471 in reading (sockFd=15) at __line_number_in_the_program__
#5  0x793bcf318b18bb01 in ?? ()
#6  0x117d0300942ff567 in ?? ()
#7  0x0000000100000000 in ?? ()
..
..
..
```

It goes till #785 with some [random] address.

reading() is the function which processes the read data in the server thread.

I suspect there something going wrong inside the socket.
Is there any way to see the data which is in the sockets(client/server) buffer without reading it?
Or any other way to debug it further with gdb?

There are already some checks to handle the read data properly but those are also not helping.

Comment: No, the socket sending/receiving buffer is managed by kernel and can't be exposed to userspace, otherwise there would be a  security problem of linux kernel

Comment: If these are [AF_INET or AF_INET6](https://linux.die.net/man/7/socket) sockets (TCP or UDP) then then then tools like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) are extremely useful for debugging this type of issue.  Wireshark lets you see what's going on in packets.  Fiddler is useful if your protocol is based on HTTP and can show a full history of request / response even for encrypted HTTPS connections.

Comment: There is almost certainly nothing going wrong inside the socket.  While it is technically possible that you've discovered a bug in the Linux kernel please remember that Linux is used on hundreds of millions of machines and most of them rely on networking.  So the chance of finding a bug which changes data inside a socket is highly unlikely.  The chance you made a mistake in your own code is pretty likely.

Comment: Thanks, @PhilipCouling.
Using Wireshark was a good idea. I'll check this if it helps.
Since the communication is happening in localhost, so will use Wireshark with the loopback address.
I acknowledge your second comment also.

Comment: Yes, there is. Look for the `MSG_PEEK` flag of `recv(2)`. Whether this is useful for debugging your program is a completely different matter -- and that is highly doubtful. Your "server" should be able to handle malformed data instead of going into a recursive trip or blowing up the stack as it apparently does.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it appears to have been answered. In comments and answer.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of both your server and client so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a stack buffer overflow problem.  If you have never heard of the GCC stack protector, now is the time to look it up.  Whilst Wireshark is the obvious tool for looking at data in flight, this is not the locus of your problem.  Your server should be proof against any and all malicious data read from the network.  This is basic good server design and implementation practice.  **You have a stack buffer overflow problem.**

Comment: This is certainly something that needs to be fixed, but necessarily an answer to the question. The OP believes the crash is caused by incorrect data being received.  The receiving program most definitely should avoid stack-overflow errors when receiving and parsing bad data (yes), but protecting against this won't fix the problem if the sender is sending bad data.